# Form validates even when validations fail

Tags: javascript, html

Hello all I need some help with this one. It seems that my application still gives an output even if the validation fails. I have tried so many ways to edit the codes but to no avail the form still allows submissions and gives an output.

I need help to get this form to be able to validate upon submission and if there is even one fail validation or error the form should not submit and gives an output. Only alerts. I need help with validation. There should be only alerts if the validation fails and the form should not even submit with an output. Please help me with this. Please see my form below. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Hello and JavaScript</title>
<script>

function doClear()
{
document.PizzaForm.customer.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.address.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.city.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.state.value = "PA";
document.PizzaForm.zip.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.phone.value = "";
document.PizzaForm.email.value = "";

document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked = false;

document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked = false;
document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked = false;
return;
}

function doSubmit() 

{
if (validateText() == false)
if (validateRadio() == false)
if (validateTops() == false)
{
return;
}

function capitalizeString(stringToCapitalize) {
    var words = stringToCapitalize.split(' ');
    for (var i=0, il=words.length; i<il; i++) {
        if (words[i].length > 0) {
            words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()
                       + words[i].substring(1, words[i].length);
        }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
}

var toppings = "";
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++){
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
            toppings += (i==0?"":",")+document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
    }

/*This alerts tells the order form is complete and it will list all the customer information such as Name address etc on a new page.*/
var OrderWindow
OrderWindow = window.open("","","status,height=500,width=500");
OrderWindow.focus();
with (OrderWindow.document)

{
write("<h1><center>Customer Order Summary</center></h1><p>")
write("Name:" + capitalizeString(document.PizzaForm.customer.value) + "<br>")
write("Address:" + document.PizzaForm.address.value + "<br>")
write("City:" + capitalizeString(document.PizzaForm.city.value) + "<br>")
write("State:" + document.PizzaForm.state.value + "<br>")
write("Zip Code:" + document.PizzaForm.zip.value + "<br>")
write("Phone Number:" + document.PizzaForm.phone.value + "<br>")
write("E-Mail:" + document.PizzaForm.email.value + "<br>")
write("Pizza Size:" + document.PizzaForm.sizes.value + "<br>")
write("Toppings:" + toppings + "<br>")
write("<h3><center>Thank You for your Order.</center></h3><p>")
}
return;
}

function validateText()

{
 if (document.PizzaForm.customer.value == "")
 {
   alert("Please enter your name");
   document.PizzaForm.customer.focus();

 }

if (document.PizzaForm.address.value == "")
 {
   alert("Please enter your address.");
   document.PizzaForm.address.focus();

 }

if (document.PizzaForm.city.value == "")
{
   alert("Please enter your City.");

}

if (document.PizzaForm.state.value == "")
{
   alert("Please enter your State.");

 }

if (document.PizzaForm.zip.value == "" ||
   isNaN( document.PizzaForm.zip.value ) ||
   document.PizzaForm.zip.value.length != 5 )
 {
   alert("Please provide a valid Zip code.");
   document.PizzaForm.zip.focus() ;

 }



    if (!/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(document.PizzaForm.phone.value)){
    alert("Please provide a valid phone number.");
    document.PizzaForm.phone.focus();
 }

var email = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
   if(!(/^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$/.test(email))){
   alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address');
   document.PizzaForm.email.focus() ;
   return false;
    }
    return true;
}


function validateRadio()/*This function validates the radio selection*/
{
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.sizes.length;i++)
        if(document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].checked)
        return document.PizzaForm.sizes[i].value;
    alert("Please choose the size of your order.");
    return false;
}

function validateTops()/*This function validates the toppings.*/
{
    if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked == false)
        {
          alert("Please select a topping of your choice.");
          return false;
        }

       return true;
}


</script>

</head> 

<body bgcolor="#EFEFCF">
 <div align="center">

<pre><h2>Pizza Menu Prices                                            Today's Selection</h2></pre>
<iframe name="left" src="prices.html" width="40%" height="380" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe name="right" src="images.html" width="35%" height="380" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe> 

<form Name ="PizzaForm">
<h1>The JavaScript Pizza Parlor</h>
<p>
<h4> Step 1: Enter your Name, Address, City, State, Phone, Zip, and email:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
Name:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address:&nbsp;<Input name="address" size="50" type="text"><br>
City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="city" size="16"type="text">
State:<select name="state"  id="selection"> 
      <option value="select state"></option>
      <option>PA</option>
      <option>NJ</option>
      <option>NY</option>
      <option>DE</option>
      </select>
&nbsp;Zip:<Input name="zip" size="8"type="text"><br>
Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="phone" size="50"type="text"><br>
Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="email" size="50"type="text"><br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4> Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4> Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Plain">Plain
</font>
</p>

<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="doSubmit()">
<input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is these three lines:

```
if (validateText() == false)
if (validateRadio() == false)
if (validateTops() == false)
{
return;
}
```

Which mean:

```
if (validateText() == false)
  if (validateRadio() == false)
    if (validateTops() == false)
    {
      return;
    }
```

So if all of those validations fail then you exit the function early, but if even one of them passes then your form will submit. Change it to:

```
if (validateText() == false || validateRadio() == false || validateTops() == false)
{
  return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work. Even when I tried your suggestion and validation fails it still gives me an output on a separate page. If validation fails it should only give an alert and then stop from form from submitting and also no outputs. If validation fails it should only give an alert. Also I think my "var OrderWindow" section needs to be check as when validation fails I still also get a po-pup windows. For example, try submitting the form with no text or selection and you should get the of the alerts one by one and then the output will still pop up. It should pop up.

Comment: @Bigpat Okay, well then what I suggested is at least one thing wrong with your code. I would suggest formatting your code better so you can tell where functions and blocks begin and end. The indentation is non-existent and it's hard to tell which brackets pair with which. After doing that, look over your code again and maybe you can find out what you've messed up.

Comment: That is my issue I'm not a coder so I wouldn't eve know where to begin. I can email you the file if you like.also what I mean to say in my last post is that there should be no pop of the output if validation fails. I'm just not sure what to do.